# Formatting output from print on respective lines?

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, formatting

I am trying to format the results of a query such that results are printed on their respective lines. For example, I am querying stores by store number and obtaining the location from a JSON file, but when printing, the store number and location are printing on separate lines:

Code Snippet: (Searching for stores 35 and 96)

```
for store, data in results.items():
    print('Store: {}'.format(store))
    if data:
        for location in data:
            print(location)
```

**Current Output:**
Store: 35
{'location': Iowa}
Store: 96
{'location': Minnesota}

**Desired output (or something similar):**
Store: 35, 'location': Iowa
Store: 96, 'location': Minnesota

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `end=''` to your first print statement should fix the problem. By specifying that the end character is an empty string you will override the default `\n` character (by default print statements end with a new line character).

```
for store, data in results.items():
    print('Store: {}'.format(store), end='')
    if data:
        for location in data:
            print(location)
```

We will only add `end=''` to the first print statement because we want the new line to print after you print out the location.

If you want to separate your prints with a `,` of course you would just add `+ ','` to your first print statement.

This will work right off the bat if you're using Python 3. If you're using Python 2.X you will have to add this line to the top of your file: `from __future__ import print_function`

Here's a simple example of this in action:

```
from __future__ import print_function

l1 = ['hello1', 'hello2', 'hello3']
l2 = ['world1', 'world2', 'world3']

for i,j in zip(l1, l2):
    print (i, end='')
    print (j)

Output:

hello1world1
hello2world2
hello3world3
```

If we took the same code but altered it slightly and just removed the `end=''`, this is what would happen:

```
from __future__ import print_function

l1 = ['hello1', 'hello2', 'hello3']
l2 = ['world1', 'world2', 'world3']

for i,j in zip(l1, l2):
    print (i)
    print (j)

Output:

hello1
world1
hello2
world2
hello3
world3
```

As you can see each line would end with a new line character, this printing a new line for each statement.

Comment: You need to add an `else` to the `if data:` in the first snippet to properly handle the case where its value is considered `False`.

Comment: @MiaElla No problem! If I was able to help you out consider marking this as the answer by hitting the check button!

Answer (score 0):

I would write all the output in a variable and print the variable only once at the end. This also allows you to save time (despite using more memory) since you need only a single access to the stdout. The code is also easier to follow (in my opinion):

```
output = ''
for store, data in results.items():
    output += 'Store: {}'.format(store)
    if data:
        for location in data:
            output += location+'\n'

# Only at the end you print your output
print(output)
```

You can also print at the end of each iteration (you still access half of the times to the stdout) with the following:

```
for store, data in results.items():
    output = 'Store: {}'.format(store)
    if data:
        for location in data:
            output += location+'\n'

    # Print only at the end of the loop
    print(output)
```

If you want a new line for each Store but not for each "location":

```
output = ''
for store, data in results.items():
    output += 'Store: {}'.format(store)
    if data:
        for location in data:
            output += location
        output += '\n'

# Only at the end you print your output
print(output)
```

I think this approach is much more flexible, easier to read in the code and is also faster.

Hope to be helpful